# Looping more than a single array in a for with twig

Tags: arrays, symfony, twig

Assume I have different simple arrays in twig with the same dimension: `arrayA`, `arrayB` and `arrayC`. A syntax like this doesn't work:

```
{% for A in arrayA, B in arrayB, C in arrayC %}
...
{% endfor %}
```

And neither does this:

```
{% for A, B, C in arrayA, arrayB, arrayC %}
...
{% endfor %}
```

How do I access more than a single array in a single `for` statement in Twig? Thank in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot specify multiple arrays in a for loop. The best you can do is something like

```
{% for i in 1..arrayA|length %}
    {{ arrayA[i] }}{{ arrayB[i] }}{{ arrayC[i] }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! That's exactly what I needed!

Comment: Glad it helped, do not hesitate to mark the answer as solved ;)

Answer (score 2):

If your keys is not numbers, you can use:

```
{% for key, A in arrayA %}
    {{ arrayA[key] }} {{ arrayB[key] }} {{ arrayC[key] }}
{% endfor %}
```